# Limiting total number of log files when multiple triggering policies are used Log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j2

All I want to achieve is,

- Log file to rollover when it crosses the 10MB mark
- Log file to rollover upon system restart
- Log file to rollover when the day changes
- Maximum 100 files in the logs folder at a time so that the size never goes beyond 1GB

Where am I going wrong in the below configuration? It actually limits 100 files per day and not 100 files in total. Log4j2 version being used is 2.11.

```
    <RollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="${logPath}/${rollingFileName}.log" filePattern="${logPath}/${rollingFileName}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %logger %-5level [%X{account}] [%t] [%X{context}] %X{version} %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <!-- Causes a rollover if the log file is older than the current JVM's start time -->
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <!-- Causes a rollover if the log file is bigger that 10 MB -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <!-- Causes a rollover once the date/time pattern no longer applies to the active file -->
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
        <!-- Allows creation of maximum 100 log files. Each of 10MB size would ensure logs folder never exceeds the size limit of 1.1GB -->
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

About the maximum number of files generated, I believe you can make use of the Custom [Delete](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover)-Action. I haven't looked into it too much though, to write down the correct code.

EDIT: You want a maximum of 100 files in the logs folder:
Look for the `exceeds` parameter - that should do what you want:
[image: exceeds - Required. The threshold count from which files will be deleted.]

EDIT2: I looked into the interval.
According to this discussions [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-820) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54403686/log4j2-defaultrolloverstrategy-for-daily-rollingfile-appender-max-not-respect) the interval is influenced by the `%d{<put_pattern_in_here>}`.

> Only a single `%d{}` is allowed in the pattern. If that pattern includes `HH` as the finest granularity then the file will rollover every hour. If it only has `dd` then it will rollover every day. If it is `MM` then it will rollover every month.
>   `Your pattern should be "/backup/$${yyyy/MM/dd}/module-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" if you want to roll over every day.`